# Delay VBA code operations without freezing Excel

Tags: vba, excel, wait

I am writing a VBA macro that will simply open another workbook, refresh all, save, and then close. It will repeat this with a second workbook. Then it refreshes and save the main workbook that the VBA code was run from. The problem I am facing is that the two workbooks being opened are using Microsoft queries to pull data from our JobBoss database and it is set to refresh this data upon opening the file. So the file opens, starts refreshing the query data and then the VBA code tries to refresh at the same time causing an error. Also, it doesn't wait for the data to finish refreshing before trying to save and close it.

Is there a way to delay each operation without freezing the Excel application?

I've tried `application.wait` but Excel is frozen during this time and the data is not refreshing in the background as once the time is over Excel unfreezes and I still receive the error about trying to do an operation while a refresh is in progress.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Refresh_All()
'
' Refresh_All Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    ChDir "Q:\Quality Control"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Q:\Quality Control\Internal Failure Log - Variable Month.xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    ChDir "Q:\Reports"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Q:\Reports\Finished-Transfer Report-variable month.xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: If you add a `DoEvents` ([read more](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118468)) in front of your `Application.Wait` code, that should avoid the issue with Excel freezing for the duration of the wait.

Comment: I did this and it still freezes. Can you show me how to properly add the doevents?

Comment: i got excel to not freeze using this: Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", 15, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop

Comment: however.... this is not allowing my microsoft query to update during the delay. Everything else is calculating except the query tables

Comment: @Dennis FYI, [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/204869) for details on how to edit your posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works after going in and disabling background refresh on all of my query tables.

```
Sub Refresh_All()
'
' Refresh_All Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Y
'
    ChDir "Q:\Quality Control"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Q:\Quality Control\Internal Failure Log - Variable Month.xlsm"
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", 2, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
DoEvents
    Loop
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
       endTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
    endTime = DateAdd("s", 5, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
    ActiveWindow.Close
    ChDir "Q:\Reports"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Q:\Reports\Finished-Transfer Report-variable month.xlsm"
        endTime = DateAdd("s", 2, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
     endTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
        endTime = DateAdd("s", 5, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
ActiveWindow.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        endTime = DateAdd("s", 10, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a better option using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects as explained here:
[Office VBA 64/32Bit Win32 API MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/42609fb79bc8353ba764)

Let me share THEIR code and translated comments:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    'https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/42609fb79bc8353ba764
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MsgWaitForMultipleObjects Lib "user32" (ByVal Count As Long, ByVal HandlesPointer As Long, ByVal WaitAll As Long, ByVal MilliSeconds As Long, ByVal WakeMask As Long) As Long
#Else
    'https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/42609fb79bc8353ba764
    Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function MsgWaitForMultipleObjects Lib "user32" (ByVal Count As Long, ByVal HandlesPointer As Long, ByVal WaitAll As Long, ByVal MilliSeconds As Long, ByVal WakeMask As Long) As Long
#End If
Public Sub WaitAPI6432(ByVal msec As Long)
'https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/42609fb79bc8353ba764
'2020 - 04 - 08
'I found the article:
'   https://web.archive.org/web/20120522222109/http://homepage1.nifty.com/MADIA/vb/vb_bbs2/200706/200706_07060026.html
'An application with a window should not call the Sleep API from its main thread,
'as it will not be able to process window messages while sleeping.
'If it is limited, there is a workaround to make the Sleep call very short and call it repeatedly together with DoEvents
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ja/jpdllpro/html/_win32_sleep.asp
'As written in .asp , it would be safer to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects API or MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
'That way, messages (redraw requests, mouse and key inputs, etc.) can be processed with DoEvents, etc., even while waiting.
'Can this be used in VBA, and can it be used in common with 64bit 32bit?
'In conclusion, it is easy to use
'The function of this procedure seems to be different in that it waits instead of stopping like Sleep.
    ' http://tokovalue.jp/function/MsgWaitForMultipleObjects.htm
    ' http://chokuto.ifdef.jp/urawaza/api/MsgWaitForMultipleObjects.html
If msec <= 0 Then
    msec = 1
End If
Dim Interval As Long
Dim tickBegin As Long
Interval = msec
tickBegin = GetTickCount()
Do
  If MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, 0, 0, Interval, &HFF&) = 0 Then
     DoEvents
  End If
  Interval = msec + tickBegin - GetTickCount()
Loop Until Interval < 0
End Sub
```

A similar reference can be found here (but needs some adaptation i think):

http://hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk/Sleep_without_locking

Answer (score -1):

Check this out,

You may have to do some editing but, I believe you will get the idea.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, bk As Workbook, bk2 As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set bk = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Quality Control\Internal Failure Log - Variable Month.xlsm")
    Set bk2 = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Reports\Finished-Transfer Report-variable month.xlsm")

        With bk
            .RefreshAll
            .Save
            .Close
        End With

        With bk2
            .RefreshAll
            .Save
            .Close
        End With

        With wb
            .RefreshAll
            .Save
            .Close
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. this is nice although I face the same problem. Excel is trying to save while the data is refreshing because there is no delay which results in the error "this action will cancel a pending refresh data command. Continue? ". It takes about 5 seconds for the data to refresh. so I need a delay which will allow the refresh to complete before trying to save. Every delay I have found so far is not allowing query tables to update. The query update starts, but doesn't run during the delays and then as soon as the delay is over it tries to save resulting in the error.

Comment: Haven't tried it , but what would happen it you refreshed all the workbooks first, then save and closed after.

Comment: turning off background refresh on the tables worked. I liked your code as it is much cleaner although I don't want both books opening and refreshing at the same time. The books are a bit data heavy and have many tables in them and I don't want to overload excel and have it start freezing. One book at a time works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `Application.Wait Now+TimeSerial(<hours>,<minutes>,<seconds>)`. Works for me whenever I need to have a delay in the code execution.

Comment: Application.wait freezes excel